# Linq to SQL: Varbinary(Max) incremental reads

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, varbinary

In SQLServer 2008 stored procedures, SUBSTRING can be used to return only part of a varbinary(MAX) column at a time from a query.

Is a similar feature available when using LINQ To SQL via C# directly in the code?

EDIT: I mean so that only a set number of bytes are loaded in code from the database and not the entire blob each time only a part of the data is required.

EDIT: Seeing as there has been only one answer, I take it that this can't be done, so I'm accepting the first answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't think so. To get that I think you'd pretty-much have to be using an `IDataReader`.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately thats what I thought, I guess the only way to do it is to use a stored procedure then.